# How do I find the code that makes featured articles display?

Tags: joomla

I want to change the layout of each featured article, so that the title is under the picture, not next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These layouts are in "/components/com_content/views/featured/". Titles are in "default_item.php". Copy it to your template's "html/com_content/featured/" folder in order to not change joomla core files.